# Android Studio - Get data from multiple records setting the same word in Edittext

Tags: android, database, sqlite, textview, android-edittext

I'm working on Android Studio and I have a table with 2 records uploaded on the DB SQLite in my project.

```
public class BaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public BaseDeDatos(Context context) {
    super(context, "verbos.db", null, 8);
}


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table verbos(id integer, verbos text, referencia text, eu text, voce text, nos text)");
        db.execSQL("insert into verbos values(1, 'agito', 'abalo', 'abala', 'abalamos', 'abalam')," +
                "(2, 'agito', 'abalava', 'abalava', 'abalávamos', 'abalavam')");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS verbos");
        db.execSQL("create table verbos(id integer, verbos text, referencia text, eu text, voce text, nos text)");
        db.execSQL("insert into verbos values(1, 'agito', 'abalo', 'abala', 'abalamos', 'abalam')," +
                "(2, 'agito', 'abalava', 'abalava', 'abalávamos', 'abalavam')");
    }
}
```

And this is my "Verbos" activity where I'm working:

```
public class Verbos extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mostrar;
EditText etVerbos;
TextView tv1, tv11, tv12, tv13, tv14, tv15, tv21, tv22, tv23, tv24, tv25;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verbos);

    etVerbos = findViewById(R.id.etIngresar);

    tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv11 = findViewById(R.id.tv11);
    tv12 = findViewById(R.id.tv12);
    tv13 = findViewById(R.id.tv13);
    tv14 = findViewById(R.id.tv14);
    tv21 = findViewById(R.id.tv21);
    tv22 = findViewById(R.id.tv22);
    tv23 = findViewById(R.id.tv23);
    tv24 = findViewById(R.id.tv24);
    mostrar = findViewById(R.id.bnMostrar);

    mostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BaseDeDatos admin = new BaseDeDatos(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
            String[] parametros = {etVerbos.getText().toString()};

            try {
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from verbos WHERE verbos =?", parametros);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                tv1.setText(cursor.getString(1));
                tv11.setText(cursor.getString(2));
                tv12.setText(cursor.getString(3));
                tv13.setText(cursor.getString(4));
                tv14.setText(cursor.getString(5));

                Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select * from verbos WHERE verbos =?", parametros);
                cursor2.moveToFirst();
                tv21.setText(cursor2.getString(2));
                tv22.setText(cursor2.getString(3));
                tv23.setText(cursor2.getString(4));
                tv24.setText(cursor2.getString(5));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El Verbo no existe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

When I set a value in the EditText (the "verbos" field in this case) and then I push the "MOSTRAR" button, the Textviews are replaced by the information in the table, depending on the "verbos" I setted. But it only works with one record (the first one), I mean, I could have more than one records with the field "verbos" be the same and I need to show them all in the others Textviews, not only the first one record.

In my example I'm trying to get the information from the first record (and replaced in the tv11, tv12, tv13, tv14) and the second record (and replaced in the tv21, tv22, tv23, tv24), when I set the word "agito" in the EditText, but it only get's me the information from the first record in both textviews (tv11, tv12..... and tv21, tv22......).

So, how could I do to get the information from multiple records with the same word setted in the Edittext?

I'll be so gratefull if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursor have two rows for agito getting next goes to row two if row two is exist, for showing list ListView or RecyclerView is used in most times, they showing 1+ rows.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        BaseDeDatos admin = new BaseDeDatos(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] parametros = {etVerbos.getText().toString()};

        try {
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from verbos WHERE verbos =?", parametros);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                tv1.setText(cursor.getString(1));
                tv11.setText(cursor.getString(2));
                tv12.setText(cursor.getString(3));
                tv13.setText(cursor.getString(4));
                tv14.setText(cursor.getString(5));
            }
            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                tv21.setText(cursor.getString(2));
                tv22.setText(cursor.getString(3));
                tv23.setText(cursor.getString(4));
                tv24.setText(cursor.getString(5));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El Verbo no existe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, it worked! But I'm having the problem with the space in the screen because I need to use 45 textview in the activity to be replaced, in table format, and some words are larger so them gonna superimpose to another. What do you recommend to me to make this tidy? I'm gonna need a horizontal scrollin for sure